# How to generate GUID using PHP (without com_create_guid)

Tags: php, guid

I have a task to generate unique identifiers. And I decided to use [Globally unique identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for this purpose. They are described with [RFC 4122 A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). (Please correct me if I'm wrong here.)

What is the reliable way to generate GUID using PHP?

Thank you.